# javascript regExp check last character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using this RexExp code `var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^([A-z0-9_.]{4,15})$');`, I want to check if last character was dot (`.`) then `.test()` returns me `false`:

```
var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^([A-z0-9_.]{4,15})$');
console.log(userIdPattern.test('Omid.my.')); // -> I need this to be false
```

and in this case return me `true`:

```
userIdPattern.test('Omid.my'); //-> true
```

Comment: `/\.$/` this should do.. returns true but later you can use exclamation mark to make it false.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use A-z?  That includes: [ ] \ ^ ` _.

Comment: @7stud yes, user name must contains "[A-z], [0-9], _, ." but dot and underscore can not be first character and last character.

Comment: So a valid user names is "Joe^]`Smith?  It's pretty clear to me that you do not know what characters are included in the range A-z because you then repeated one of those characters by writing '_' in your character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the update, a more appropriate regex might be:

```
var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^([A-Za-z0-9\[\]\\^`][A-z0-9_.]{2,13}[A-Za-z0-9\[\]\\^`])$');
```

That is, if you want to include other special characters in the usernames like 7stud mentioned in his comment and only exclude `.` and `_` from the first and last characters.

Otherwise, to prevent those characters, I would suggest:

```
var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.]{2,13}[A-Za-z0-9])$');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7Lzq/1/) to test.

Comment: the first one works if i use it like this : `RegExp(^([A-Za-z0-9\\^`][A-z0-9_.]{2,13}[A-Za-z0-9\\^`])$)` but as 7stud saying its not what i'm looking for.

Comment: and second one just returns false.

Comment: @OMiD Okay, it works now. Seems like JS takes character classes apart when they are in square brackets, unlike some other regex engines. Try to see if the edited regex works :)

Comment: @OMiD Are you allowing `[]\^\`` in the usernames?

Comment: nope ! it was a mistake in my first regExp. only contains "[a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], _, ." but dot and underscore can not be at first or last character.

Comment: @OMiD Use the second regex. I have now included a link to a fiddle and it seems to work for me.

Comment: yey ! it works but still "_" not working ! i used this : `var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.]{2,13}[A-Za-z0-9])$');` is it ok?

Comment: @OMiD Oh, you need to have underscore as well? Oops, missed that one xD

Comment: @OMiD And yes, it's okay :)

Comment: Thank you, it's working now, {2,13} what about this ? why it's not {4,15} ?

Comment: @OMiD Initially, you had `{4,15}` to mean that the username had to be between 4 and 15 characters right? Now that you have one obligatory character at the beginning and one at the end, you need to remove 2 characters from the numbers! E.g. of 15 char username: `ThisIsAUserName` The T will get matched by the first `[A-Za-z0-9]`, `hisIsAUserNam` will match 13 characters in `[A-Za-z0-9_.]{2,13}` and the e will match the last `[A-Za-z0-9]`. (total 15)

Comment: In JavaScript, you should generally use a regular expression literal — not totally necessary, but it looks nice and you don’t have to escape as much sometimes :) `var userIdPattern = /^([A-Za-z0-9][\w.]{2,13}[A-Za-z0-9])$/);` (@OMiD)

Comment: @minitech So that's why `[\w.]` wasn't working! Well, learned something new about JS today! Thanks for the tip minitech ^^

Answer (score 4):

You can make it like this

```
^([A-z0-9_.]{3,14}[A-z0-9])$
```

Edit after reading your comment

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.]{2,13}[a-z0-9]$
```

[Preview](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%5Ba-z0-9%5D%5Ba-z0-9_.%5D%7B3,13%7D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%24&input=example%0AEXAMPLE%0Aexample_1%0A1st_example%0Aexample_%0A_example%0A.example%0Aexample.%0Aexample.3%0A3.example)

Also I suggest you use flag the `i` to ignore case:

```
var userIdPattern = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.]{3,13}[a-z0-9]$', 'i');
```

Comment: thanks, another thing: username must contains "[A-z], [0-9], _, ." but dot and underscore can not be at first or last character.

Comment: @OMiD "Must contain" or "can contain"?

Comment: it was a mistake in my first regExp. username can only contains ` [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], _ , . ` but dot and underscore can not be at first or last character.